# C++: Does passing address of a reference as a pointer gives undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have following code,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
    int z = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = z;
}

// Driver Code
int main()
{
    int a = 45, b = 35;
    auto& a_ref = a;
    cout << "a = " << a_ref << " b = " << b << "\n";

    swap(&a_ref, &b);

    cout << "After Swap with pass by pointer\n";
    cout << "a = " << a << " b = " << b << "\n";
}
```

As can be seen, I first get a reference of `a` then pass it as a pointer, I am wondering will this give `undefined` sometimes?

Comment: Code looks fine to me. Taking the address of a reference is a perfectly normal thing to do.

Comment: There _are_ times when _using_ the address of a reference leads to undefined behavior, but those fall under the broader category of dangling-pointer / object lifetime issues and are not specific to references. In general, and including your example, there is no problem. Taking the address of a reference is the same as taking the address of the object it references.

Comment: You should be careful however about mixing `using namespace std;` with your own function called `swap` because there is also a function called `std::swap`. So in your program you have two different functions both of which are accessed with the name `swap`. Obviously this can lead to confusion or error. We had a question like this just the other day.

Comment: the function should take references rather than pointers, unless a `nullptr` is valid and expected input, which it isnt. And then there is already `std::swap` which you should use rather than writing your own

Comment: Yes!! The advice in the above comment is something that doesn't seem to be commonly understood below some threshold of experience. It may also be somewhat of a hang-up due to the relationship of C to C++. References give you a compile-time guarantee that an object is valid, which not only makes code safer, but also brings implied semantics to an interface. If you use that paradigm consistently, then it also brings implied semantics to situations when you _do_ accept a pointer value.

Comment: Think of a reference as an *alias*.  In some way, it's philosophically closer to `#define a_ref a` than it is to considering it as a separate variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't take the address of a reference. When a variable of reference type appears in an expression, it always evaluates to the object (or function) to which it refers. So the expression `&a_ref` is, by all means, equivalent to `&a`.

[[expr.type]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type#1):

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to `T`”, [...]. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference